# Two contradictory definitions for "count with" and a poem by Rudyard Kipling

Tags: ambiguity

The definition for "count with" from the two sources below seems opposite to each other:

[macmillandictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/count-with):

> **to depend on something or someone**
>
> We currently count with the support of over 15 state senators.

[thefreedictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/count+with):

> **to be important to someone.**
>
> Your cooperation really counts with me.
>
> All my efforts do not count with her.

Are they both actively used (regionally, maybe)?

In particular, which definition should be taken for this line from [a poem](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems-and-poets/poems/detail/46473) by Rudyard Kipling?

> If you can talk with crowds and keep your virtue,
>
> Or walk with Kings—nor lose the common touch,
>
> If neither foes nor loving friends can hurt you,
>
> If all men **count with** you, but none too much;

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: The Macmillian definition/usage quoted is novel to me.

Comment: I would not rely on the macmillan dictionary. I've come across it before, it seems to be purely made up of submissions from the public. Anyone can submit and the bar for acceptance of contributions appears low.

Comment: @Spagirl - This pulls us immediately into the tired old debate: Is a dictionary descriptive or prescriptive? The problem with macmillan is not that it publishes submissions, but that it gives no hint of how widely the definition is used. One of the great (or horrible, depending on your taste) things about English is that anybody can come up with a word or meaning, and if enough people find it useful it becomes part of the language. The other extreme is L'Academie Francaise, which claims absolute jurisdiction over what is, and is not, proper French vocabulary.

Comment: The Macmillan example is odd. I’d avoid using it.  The Kipling quote is clearly the “important to” definition.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Yes, what i was getting at was that macmillan appear to apply little or no rigour to approval for inclusion, so it seems that one person's misapprehension can acquire spurious authority.

Comment: @Spagirl - Not my point. If Joe or Jane Blow wants to use a word in an idiosyncratic manner, that is their business, and it is "correct" in their terms. Of course, they may find that nobody around them understands what they are saying, but that's chance you take. My point is that if dictionaries are descriptive, rather than prescriptive, such an idiosyncratic usage is valid, and the dictionary's job is not to reject it simply because it is not widely used. You seem to be firmly in the prescriptive camp, but you should be aware that many folk disagree with you.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I'm not in the prescriptive camp in the slightest. I've advocated caution in use of an open dictionary that does not, itself, give the user any clue as to the prevalence or idiosyncratic nature of definitions which it includes.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast If such an idiosyncratic usage is valid, but possibly makes people misunderstand the user, that is a chance Jane or Joe can take - but shouldn't a dictionary signal such idiosyncrasy to the reader who looks up the entry? If one adopts this usage from Macmillan believing it to be standard English (it's in the dictionary, right?), one is not taking a chance, one is simply misled. That has nothing to do with the dictionary being descriptive or prescriptive, it simply means the dictionary is incomplete - it leaves out important information on the usages that it lists.

Comment: @oerkelens - You are preaching to the choir. If you would care to reread my original comment you will find, "The problem with macmillan is not that it publishes submissions, but that it gives no hint of how widely the definition is used."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most or all of the conditional statements in that poem involve being *virtuous* or *bold*, often in cases that involve *remaining virtuous in the face of having power*.  Because of that, Kipling likely meant the second of the two definitions you gave.

If it meant

> If all men **depend on** you, but none too much

It would be a judgement on the "men," not on "you."  On the other hand:

> If all men **are important to** you, but none too much
>
> ...
>
> Yours is the Earth and everything that’s in it,
>
> And—which is more—you’ll be a Man, my son!

Here Kipling is indicating that it is virtuous to value all people, but not to put too much value on any one person to the point where it impairs your judgment or compromises your values.